# Не считывает .txt c++

Tags: c++, c++17

C++17   -   VisualStudio 2017
Хотел написать свою программу, чтобы попрактиковаться. Суть программы в том, чтобы взять имена файлов в папке(через регулярку), и сравнить на совпадение и соответствие со списком в .txt файле(Типо сервак). Значит получил я имена. Хочу сравнить. Использую библиотеку fstream, дальше открываю это все через ifstream(см. код).

```
string f = "server_mods.txt";
    string str;
    ifstream file;
    file.open(f);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        while (!file.eof())
        {
            file >> str;
            cout << str << endl;
            // getline() не работает, все так же
            // по символьно через char* тоже не робит
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error, when opening file!" << endl;
    }
```

Файл server_mods.txt находится в директории с проектом visual studio. В нем только АНГЛИЙСКИЕ символы, кодировку пробовал ANSI UTF-8, не помогает. Что выводит? Да ничего не выводит просто, просто пустота в консоли(cmd), а sizeof(str), показывает 28.
Что делать? Может что-то не так с visual studio? C++17
Я начинающий)

---

Все дело было в пути до файла. Перед этим задавалась другая директория через другой заголовок)

Comment: `sizeof(str)` никакого отношения к хранящейся строке не имеет, `while (!file.eof())` - неверное применение  проверки конца файла, правда, это не имеет отношения к вашей проблеме. Сообщение о том, что файл не открыт, не выводится? Укажите точное полное имя файла с указанием пути - чтоб быть уверенным, что файл указан верно; текущий каталог при запуске может вполне быть не тем, куда вы положили файл...

Comment: Имя файла правильное, если букву поменять, то выходит ошибка, что невозможно открыть. Как мне быть? Есть ли другие варианты чтения файлов? Например через библиотеку <windows>?

Comment: Я смотрел урок на youtube. Мужик рассказывает и показывает, я можно сказать перекопипастил его код к себе, у него работает, у меня нет. Может в visual studio проблема?

Comment: Значит, что-то не то в самом файле, его содержимом. Приведите весь текст и содержимое вашего файла (можете выложить все на файлообменник и в комментарии дать ссылку). Грешить на компилятор не стоит :)

Comment: Вот файл
https://dropmefiles.com/FcLSE

Comment: попробуйте сначала считать только одну строку, убрав ваш цикл   while (!file.eof())...

Comment: В вашем варианте у меня все скомпилировалось и считалось (ну, как и запрошено, пословно с ошибкой при последнем чтении из-за неправильного eof). VC++2017. Вот весь cpp-файл: https://dropmefiles.com/IHIF0 У вас при компиляции никаких лишних сообщений? При выполнении? Вы работаете из среды? Может, быстро схлопывается окно и вы не успеваете увидеть вывод?

Comment: В main добавьте в конце `return 0` и ставьте на него точку останова чтобы увидеть вывод. Или выберите в студии `Tools / Options / Debugging / General` и сбросьте галку в самой нижней опции `Automatically close the console when debugging stops`.

Comment: Я знаю что консоль закрывается, поэтому у меня прописно system("pause"), может быть из-за этого.
Вот исходник моего всего кода, кода этой программы.
Я создал метод readMods(), и все равно ничего не выводит в консоль
https://dropmefiles.com/4pbEv     -   main.cpp
https://dropmefiles.com/nnBsT     -   Скрины из консоли

Comment: Кстати, раз уж C++17, может стоит использоватьт [<filesystem>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/filesystem)?

Comment: Как с помощью <filesystem> прочитать файл, и значение кинуть в переменную? Есть метод какой-то?

Comment: Вам стоит не кидать ссылки на левые файлообменники, а привести [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) непосредственно в вопросе.